# RSS Feeds or API to access REIT information?

Tags: api, finance

I have a Web application that needs to display up to date information on REITs and tickers like AX.UN, BEI.UN, CAR.UN etc..

For example, I need to automate consumption of information on pages such as 
http://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q?s=AX-UN.TO

Are there rss feeds or apis I can use to import this kind of data?  I don't want to copy and paste this information into my website on a daily basis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the very site you link to, there's a small link that says "download data".  If you have a database with the symbols you want to track, it would be pretty easy to construct that download URL on the fly, query it, parse the CSV, and load that data into your database for display on your website.

**ETA**: Here's the link:

http://ca.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=AX-UN.TO&f=sl1d1t1c1ohgv&e=.csv

Just have your program replace the "AX-UN.TO" with whatever symbol you want, and it should grab the data for that symbol.

Comment: thanks.  Any idea how likely and how frequently yahoo may "change something" such that I will have to write a new parser each time?  I prefer an RSS or an API approach because my gut tells me they are more stable....

Comment: I have no idea, probably not often if at all, but that's always a risk - even with an API.  There are real APIs out there for getting stock data, but no free ones that I know of.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://www.mergent.com/servius - particularly the Historical Securities Data API. Not sure if it has REIT data - if it doesn't, it may be available by special arrangement from them.